# htaccess 301 redirect with wildcard to a single page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We took over a website with about a kabillion pages in the old site root directory done in htm that need to be retired. I want to do a 301 redirect from the pages to the index.php in the root directory of the new site using a wildcard. An example of the page naming structure follows:

```
oldpage_dees.htm
oldPage_dat.htm
oldPage_deeudderting.htm
```

and so on. As stated, I need them redirected to the index.php in the root directory. Going by examples and discussions here I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/oldpage_([\w]*).htm$ /index.php  [R=301,L]
```

but I get a 404 error.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As `.htaccess` is directory level configuration file, you don't need to specify forward slash, I think this will do the job:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^oldpage_([\w]*).htm$ index.php  [R=301,L]
```

Meanwhile, you can use the following [.htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to debug your rewrite rules.